# Is there any way of viewing spoilers on mobile?

Tags: discussion, formatting

Quite often questions will have text like the following:

> This text is hidden!

Is it possible to view this text on a mobile as you clearly can't hover on mobile?
It is possible to click edit and read the question that way but it doesn't make for good reading without the proper formatting

Comment: I just realized I was using the Chrome app for iPhone 4 and I had clicked Request Desktop Site. When I was in proper mobile mode it shows exactly as the screenshot below shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I literally just tried (iPhone 4S)

[image]

Not sure about Android usage though.

Comment: Well, on an iPhone 4 - you briefly get shown the spoiler, before the javascript is executed and hides it.

Answer (score 3):

As @TylerShads indicates, stackexchange looks like it has some Javascript which allows such spoilers to be shown on iOS Webkit based phones.  I cannot confirm this works on Android either, but its another Webkit based platform so it is probably a similar user experience.

I did notice that on the iPhone 4 - it briefly showed me the spoiler before the js executed and hid the text.  So it is not the best behavior for true spoilers.

However, I would like to make a point about the use of the spoiler markup.  As said in the FAQ, please keep spoiler markup to a minimum.  If the question is tagged appropriately or the title of the question makes clear what movie is being discussed, I see no reason to use spoiler markup at all - *the exception being if the question or answer has a spoiler relating to another movie or tv show*.  Spoilers in titles are discouraged too.

Over use of spoiler markup is noise and will be removed.