# Do you stop receiving rep for meta questions once you reach 1k?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've only recently passed 1k rep and up until now any question I asked on meta counted towards my overall rep.

I asked a [question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/611/is-there-any-way-of-viewing-spoilers-on-mobile) since I reached 1k rep and it got 3 upvotes but I didn't receive any rep for it. So I'm wondering do you stopping reaching rep for meta questions once you reach 1k?

Comment: I think you might be mistaken, I don't think voting on meta has ever counted towards site rep - below 1k or above.

Comment: I was almost certain that you recieved rep from meta normally but I looked through my normal rep and there was nothing from meta so clearly I was mistaken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Voting is different on Meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences)

That said, your meta rep is just a reflection of your main site rep, the only difference being [Meta StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Technically, you do have an *internal* rep on meta, it is just not displayed.